# Where is master password for Firefox stored. Is this password is same as the master password asked for NSS?

Tags: fips-140

While working on FIPS requirement. I found that there is a master password required for LibNSS to access all primary cryptographic module.

Similarly Firefox in FIPS mode also needs a master password although it is the password used to protect user credential information and certificates.

Keeping the fact in mind Firefox uses NSS, I am a bit confused. Both NSS master password and Firefox required master password are different or same.

I also want to know where this master password stored. Can I set it using a script ?

Comment: IIRC the master password is used to encrypt the keys.db (or similar), ie the key-database and as such if you don't share this file with the current Firefox profile they should have separate passwords.

Comment: Thanks for replying. As far as i know it is not required to use a single keys.db for separate applications consuming nss. If there are multiple keys.db used by different applications, Do we need to have different master password for each of them.

Comment: You don't _have to_ but you really should.